# Are peekCString and peekCStringLen lazy?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ffi

I have a C function that creates a null terminated string and returns a pointer to it, there is also corresponding deallocation function.

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "get_str" getStr :: IO CString
foreign import ccall unsafe "free_str" freeStr :: CString -> IO ()
```

I want to create a Haskell String from the returned CString, and free CString as soon as possible.

```
do cStr <- getStr
   str <- peekCString cStr
   freeStr cStr
   -- here str is used
```

Is it safe to free cStr before str is used? In other words, does peekCString create Haskell String all at once, or is it created lazily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

peekCString is strict -- it doesn't suspend the loop via unsafeInterleaveIO, for example, so once you have the head of the string, you've definitely already computed the tail. Here's the implementation:

```
peekCAString cp = do
  l <- lengthArray0 nUL cp
  if l <= 0 then return "" else loop "" (l-1)
  where
    loop s i = do
        xval <- peekElemOff cp i
        let val = castCCharToChar xval
        val `seq` if i <= 0 then return (val:s) else loop (val:s) (i-1)
```

Comment: If I have a C function which has no side effects and returns strings, can I fool Haskell into thinking that `getStr >>= peekCString` is not an `IO String`, but rather a `String`?  It is declared as `peekCString    :: CString -> IO String` at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Foreign-C-String.html#peekCString