# How can I make data that is allocated manually be garbage-collected in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, memory-management, garbage-collection, ffi

I'm thinking about a FFI calling some C functions from Haskell.

If a memory buffer is used to hold some data and is allocated "manually" and then it is used in Haskell computations, can I somehow rely on the garbage collector to free it when it is not needed anymore.

As for the manual allocations, there are basically two ways (but the difference doesn't seem to be essential for my question):

- allocating a buffer in Haskell, then passing it to C function, like in [`fdRead`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0/docs/src/System-Posix-IO-Common.html#fdRead)
- allocating a buffer in C (with `malloc`, like in GNU's [`asprintf`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28562512/94687)), then returning the pointer to Haskell

In both examples (`fdRead` or `asprintf`) there is also a problem that the data type stored in the buffer is not suitable for a Haskell program, therefore it is copied&converted to be used in Haskell (with `peekCString`). (I'll put the code below.) After the copying&conversion happens, the buffer is freed (in both cases).

However, I'm thinking about a more efficient interface, where the Haskell would directly use the data as it is stored by a C function (without a conversion). (I haven't yet explored, say, alternative implementations of `String` and related functions: whether there is one among them which can work directly with some kind of C strings.)

If I follow this route, then there is one global problem: how to control the disposal of the allocated buffers. (For side-effects-free functions--except for the allocation--I could even wrap the calls in `unsafePerformIO` or declare them so that they are not an `IO`.)

### Examples with conversion and immediate freeing

#### allocating in Haskell:

[fdRead](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0/docs/src/System-Posix-IO-Common.html#fdRead) (here [`allocaBytes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:allocaBytes) must care for the freeing):

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- fd{Read,Write}

-- | Read data from an 'Fd' and convert it to a 'String' using the locale encoding.
-- Throws an exception if this is an invalid descriptor, or EOF has been
-- reached.
fdRead :: Fd
       -> ByteCount -- ^How many bytes to read
       -> IO (String, ByteCount) -- ^The bytes read, how many bytes were read.
fdRead _fd 0 = return ("", 0)
fdRead fd nbytes = do
    allocaBytes (fromIntegral nbytes) $ \ buf -> do
    rc <- fdReadBuf fd buf nbytes
    case rc of
      0 -> ioError (ioeSetErrorString (mkIOError EOF "fdRead" Nothing Nothing) "EOF")
      n -> do
       s <- peekCStringLen (castPtr buf, fromIntegral n)
       return (s, n)

-- | Read data from an 'Fd' into memory.  This is exactly equivalent
-- to the POSIX @read@ function.
fdReadBuf :: Fd
          -> Ptr Word8 -- ^ Memory in which to put the data
          -> ByteCount -- ^ Maximum number of bytes to read
          -> IO ByteCount -- ^ Number of bytes read (zero for EOF)
fdReadBuf _fd _buf 0 = return 0
fdReadBuf fd buf nbytes =
  fmap fromIntegral $
    throwErrnoIfMinus1Retry "fdReadBuf" $
      c_safe_read (fromIntegral fd) (castPtr buf) nbytes

foreign import ccall safe "read"
   c_safe_read :: CInt -> Ptr CChar -> CSize -> IO CSsize
```

#### allocating in C

`getValue.c`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

#include "getValue.h"

char * getValue(int key) {
  char * value;
  asprintf(&value, "%d", key); // TODO: No error handling!
  // If memory allocation wasn't possible, or some other error occurs,  these  functions  will
  // return -1, and the contents of strp is undefined.
  return value;
}
```

`GetValue.hs` (here I explicitly call `free` after the conversion [is actually done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739331/94687)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Foreign hiding (unsafePerformIO)
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C.Types

import Foreign.C.String(peekCString)

import System.IO.Unsafe

getValue :: Int -> IO String
getValue key = do
  valptr <- c_safe_getValue (fromIntegral key)
  value <- peekCString valptr
  c_safe_free valptr
  return value

foreign import ccall safe "getValue.h getValue" c_safe_getValue :: CInt -> IO (Ptr CChar)
foreign import ccall safe "stdlib.h free" c_safe_free :: Ptr a -> IO ()

value :: Int -> String
value = unsafePerformIO . getValue -- getValue has no side-effects, so we wrap it.

{- A simple test: -}
main1 = putStrLn (value 2)

{- A test with an infinite list, which employs laziness: -}
keys = [-5..]
results = map value keys

main = foldr (>>) 
             (return ())
             (map putStrLn (take 20 results))
```

If there wasn't the (ineffective) conversion&copying step, I would need to rely on garbage collector for freeing, but have no idea how to define such things in Haskell.

Comment: Have you seen `ForeignPtr`? It's like a `Ptr` with an attached finalizer that will be called whenever it is GC'd: from that you should be able to call C to free the previously allocated object.

Comment: @chi Great! [It sounds like](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html) exactly the thing I was looking for. (Perhaps make this an answer so that I could accept it?)

Comment: @chi Now I'll have to look for `String`-analogues implemented on top of `ForeignPtr CChar`. Or on top of `Ptr CChar`: so that I can work with them inside the bracket `withForeignPtr`...

Answer (score 2):

The [`ForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html) type acts as a `Ptr` with an attached finalizer. When the `ForeignPtr` gets garbage collected, the finalizer is run, and can call the C side to free the pointer using the proper function.

Since the pointer is no longer accessible from Haskell, this is typically the right moment to free it.